# simplify/solve nonlinear equations for constrained least squares problem

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, nonlinear-system

I am trying to find a simple, ideally closed form formula for the (not necessarily unique) unit vector $\vec{x}$ minimizing total squared cosine distance from a collection of unit vectors $\vec{v_i}$. In other words I want to solve

$$\operatorname*{argmin}_{||\vec{x}|| = 1} \sum_i (1 - \vec{v_i} \cdot \vec{x})^2.$$

I have attempted to solve this problem using Lagrange multipliers with objective function

$$f(\vec{x}, \lambda) = \sum_i \left(1 - \frac{\vec{v_i} \cdot \vec{x}}{||\vec{x}||}\right)^2 + \lambda (1 - ||\vec{x}||^2).$$

But the system of equations that I get is not easy to work with:

$$\vec{v} = \left( \left(\sum_i \vec{v_i} \otimes \vec{v_i} \right) + ( \vec{v} \cdot \vec{x} - (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{x})^2 - \lambda ) I\right) \vec{x}$$
and
$$||\vec{x}|| = 1$$

where $\vec{v} = \sum_i \vec{v_i}$. In contrast, without the constraint $||\vec{x}|| = 1$ the problem has a beautiful set of critical points:

$$\vec{v} = \left( \sum_i \vec{v_i} \otimes \vec{v_i} \right) \vec{x}.$$

At this point I am having trouble proceeding. I could stop here and use numerical methods to find approximate solutions but can this system of equations be further simplified or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would diagonalize the covariance matrix $\sum_i v_i^Tv_i$ first. That matrix is symmetric (and positive semidefinite), so it has an orthogonal eigenbasis. The eigendirections can be found by some standard numeric methods.

After the orthonormal basis transform, the matrix $\sum_i v_i^Tv_i$ is diagonal with consisting of the eigenvalues along the diagonal; let $c_j$ be the $j$th diagonal element. It is reasonable to compute the vector $\sum v_i$ as well; let $s=\sum_i v_i$.

After that, your system of equations will be 
$$ (c_j-\lambda)x_j=s_j \quad (j=1,2,\ldots,d); \qquad \sum_{j=1}^d x_i^2=1 $$
where $d$ is the dimension of the space we work in.
Hence, we have to solve the $2d$-degree equation 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^d \left(\frac{s_j}{c_j-\lambda}\right)^2 =1 
$$
for $\lambda$, then we obtain 
$$
x_j=\frac{s_j}{c_j-\lambda} \quad(j=1,\ldots,d).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment but there is one thing that I don't understand. Why do the $v \cdot x$ terms not appear in the system of equations?

Comment: In the equation only the gradient should appear. Your goal is to minimize $f(x)=x^tCx-2s^tx$, where $C$ is the covariance matrix, under the constraint $|x|^2=1$. Then Lagrange provides the equation $\nabla f=\lambda\cdot\nabla(|x|^2)$, i.e. $2x^tC-2s^t=\lambda\cdot 2x^t$; in the $j$th co-ordinate this is $c_jx_j-s_j=\lambda\cdot x_j$.

Comment: You are right, I am an idiot. When I added the Lagrange multiplier I computed the cosine distance without the assumption that $||x|| = 1$, which requires normalizing by $||x||$, but it is equivalent to minimize the "unnormalized" dot product because the functions agree on the region where the constraint is satisfied. Removing normalization kills the $v \cdot x$ terms so one is simply left with $s = (\sum_i v_i^t v - \lambda I) x$, using your notation.

Comment: In light of my previous comment, my question is far more trivial than I thought but I will still accept your answer and award you the bounty because it is nonetheless correct and you led me to identify this stupid mistake.

Comment: Thanks... "To err is human - but it feels divine."  ;-)